# Bypassing stack guard- Buffer overflow

Tags: c++, security, buffer-overflow

I am taking a secure computer system course and I am very new to the subject. I am having a problem with an assignment where I need to get a shell by overflowing the buffer in a target program (target.cc). I cannot make any changes in target.cc but I can send the parameters to the target file.

here is the code.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
class SubStringReference
{
    const char *start;
    size_t len;

public:
    SubStringReference(const char *s, size_t l) : start(s), len(l) { }
    virtual ~SubStringReference() { }
    virtual const char *getStart() const { return start; }
    virtual int getLen() const { return len; }
};

void print_sub_string(const SubStringReference& str)
{
    char buf[252];
    if (str.getLen() >= sizeof buf)
    {
        // Only copy sizeof(buf) - 1 bytes plus a null
        memcpy(buf, str.getStart(), sizeof(buf) - 1);
        buf[sizeof(buf) - 1] = '\0'; // null-terminate
    }
    else
    {   
        printf("by passed mem check\n");
        // The length is less than the size of buf so just string copy.
        strcpy(buf, str.getStart());
        buf[str.getLen()] = '\0'; // null-terminate to get just the substring
    }
    puts(buf);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc != 4)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s STRING START LENGTH\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    const char *s = argv[1];
    int total_len = strlen(s);
    int start = atoi(argv[2]);
    int len = atoi(argv[3]);
    if (start < 0 || start >= total_len)
    {
        fputs("start is out of range!\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    if (len < 0 || start + len > total_len)
    {
        fputs("length is out of range!\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    SubStringReference str(s + start, len);
    print_sub_string(str);
    return 0;
}
```

Since this program is stackguard protected the program gets aborted before returning. Is there any other way that i can overflow the buffer and get a shell??

Thanks.

Edit - I am running this on a Qemu arm emulator with g++ compiler

Comment: You probably need some settings to remove the stackguard and enable code execution from the stack. This is all dependent on the OS and compiler you use. But you forgot to tell us those details.

Comment: i'm sorry. i have edited the ques. I cannot disable the stackguard as it is a requirement of the assignment. i have to bypass the stackguard

Comment: How large is 'int' on your system?

Comment: If you're at a loss, just brute-force fuzz this thing and see when it explodes.

Comment: 'int' is 4 bytes

Comment: And do you know how stack is protected on your system?

Comment: it uses a radom canary value right after buffer

Comment: Do you have means to know the exact value of this canary?

Comment: No.. the value of the canary keeps changing every time the program is run.

Comment: how big is this canary? 8bit? 16bit? I guess you need to retry until you get lucky?

Comment: It's a 4 bit Canary... And by the way I found the solution for this.. thank you

Comment: Feel free to post it here, you are allowed to answer your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vulnerability can be exploited by overflowing the buffer and overwriting the address of `str.getLen()` function so as to point to the shell code. Since the canary check is done at the end of the function, shell is got before the canary is checked.

Comment: Could you please share a sample input, which would trigger that?